# Timer Position Showing Double in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a small game using JQuery.

I created a button with image, when I click on the button, timer starts to count down, but before the button clicking event, the timer is position at the bottom, and once I click the button, timer appears on top(which is where I would like it to be), couldn't figure out why.....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#startBtn").on("click", function() {
        $(this).hide();
        });
    });

    //set and display timer on button click

    var timer = null;
    var time = 0;
    $("#startBtn").click(function() {
        time = 120;
        showTimer();
        timer = setInterval(showTimer, 1000);
    });

    function showTimer() {
        if(time < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }
        function pad(value) {
            return(value < 10?'0':"") + value;
        }
        $("#timer").text(Math.floor(time/60)+':' + pad(time%60));
        time--;
    }
```

```css
body {
background-image: url(https://www.joblo.com/assets/images/oldsite/newsimages1/avengers-infinity-war-main.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%, 90%;
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 100px;
    color:white;
}

#startBtn {
    width: 250px;
    height:250px;
    margin-left:450px;
    margin-right:250px;
    margin-top: 180px;
}

.timeRemaining {
    color:white;
    margin-left:350px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#timer {
    color: white;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Trivia Game</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Trivia Game</h1>
        </div>

        
        <input type="image" id="startBtn" src="assets/images/start.jpg" value="click me" onclick="myFunction()"/> 
        

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="timeRemaining">
                <p>Time Remaining:
                    <span id="timer"></span>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>

    <script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is showing error on running

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have margin-top of  margin-top: 180px; for button and you are hiding it when you click on the button. Once the button is hidden the margin that is given to the button is lost as well that is why the timer comes on top. do you want to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you click button it disappears and timer was taking it's position, change button position to bottom of `timeRemaining` div and remove  `onclick="myFunction()"`, you already clicked on `id`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#startBtn").on("click", function() {
        $(this).hide();
        });
    });

    //set and display timer on button click

    var timer = null;
    var time = 0;
    $("#startBtn").click(function() {
        time = 120;
        showTimer();
        timer = setInterval(showTimer, 1000);
    });

    function showTimer() {
        if(time < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }
        function pad(value) {
            return(value < 10?'0':"") + value;
        }
        $("#timer").text(Math.floor(time/60)+':' + pad(time%60));
        time--;
    }
```

```css
body {
background-image: url(https://www.joblo.com/assets/images/oldsite/newsimages1/avengers-infinity-war-main.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%, 90%;
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 100px;
    color:white;
}

#startBtn {
    width: 250px;
    height:250px;
    margin-left:450px;
    margin-right:250px;
    margin-top: 180px;
}

.timeRemaining {
    color:white;
    margin-left:350px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#timer {
    color: white;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Trivia Game</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Trivia Game</h1>
        </div>

        
        
        

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="timeRemaining">
                <p>Time Remaining:
                    <span id="timer"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <input type="image" id="startBtn" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" value="click me" /> 



    </div>

    <script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```